# The regular expression '/ code.? * (\ w {4}) /' does not work

Tags: javascript

It doesn't work only on the cloudflare website.
I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

```
var s="code:8djsAAAA0000";
var pw = s.match(/code.? *(\w{4})/);//it does not work
```

Comment: Which part are you exactly are you trying to extract, this? `8djsAAAA0000`

Comment: Four strings after 'code:'

Comment: @XxyLiu: Define "doesn't work" (ideally in the form of a true [MCVE]). In my browser console it's just fine; the result in `pw` is `[ "code:8djs", "8djs" ]`.

Comment: Yes, it works normally in browsers or other places, but it doesn't work in cloudflare's workers, which is strange

Comment: Forget to add escape character!!!